# Require checking an input and máximum of 4 options checked

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of checkboxes where the user can choose flavours, but I don't know how to make the user choose from 1 to máximum 4 flavours, **making 1 required and 4 max.**

If I put required on each of them, then every flavour will be required, and I need to be required that the user can check ANY of the flavours.

¿Any help on how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

**HTML**

```
<div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Jamón" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Jamón">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/jamon_781f5c81-af75-48aa-bf1b-982fea9741f9.jpg?v=1580515764" alt="" />
    <label for="Jamón">Jamón</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bacon" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Bacon Parmesano">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/bacon_81ce213f-0281-48a3-8980-a100956f3e3a.jpg?v=1580515764" alt="" />
    <label for="bacon">Bacon Parmesano</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="trufa" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Trufa">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/trufa.jpg?v=1580516040" alt="" />
    <label for="trufa">Trufa Negra</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pollocurry" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Pollo al curry">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/curry.jpg?v=1580515361" alt="" />
    <label for="pollocurry">Pollo al curry</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pollocurry" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Pollo al curry">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/asado.jpg?v=1580515763" alt="" />
    <label for="pollocurry">Pollo asado</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="quesoazul" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Queso Azul">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/azul.jpg?v=1580516040" alt="" />
    <label for="quesoazul">Queso Azul</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="marisco" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Marisco">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/marisco_d6ed6f7f-71d1-4774-a789-04527f639fe5.jpg?v=1580515764" alt="" />
    <label for="marisco">Marisco</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="espinacas" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Espinacas">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/espi.jpg?v=1580515764" alt="" />
    <label for="espinacas">Espinacas</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="bacalao" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Bacalao">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/bac.jpg?v=1580515764" alt="" />
    <label for="bacalao">Bacalao</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yorkqueso" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="York Queso">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/york.jpg?v=1580516040" alt="" />
    <label for="yorkqueso">York Queso</label>
  </div>
    <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="puerros" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Puerros confitados">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/puerros_113f7bf7-4319-47c9-a689-db07db189b32.jpg?v=1580515361" alt="" />
    <label for="puerros">Puerros confitados</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="boletus" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Boletus">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/boletus_1012973f-3a92-4097-80a8-26268137bf9d.jpg?v=1580515866" alt="" />
    <label for="boletus">Boletus</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cocido" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Cocido">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/cocido.jpg?v=1580516251" alt="" />
    <label for="cocido">Cocido Madrileño</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chipis" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Chipirones">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/chipis.jpg?v=1580516251" alt="" />
    <label for="chipis">Chipirones</label>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar small-3 large-2 columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chistorra" hidden-data="Sabores" onchange="fillHidden('Sabores')" value="Chistorra">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/5554/files/txistorra_32a4b480-1147-46ce-a245-5af947b0e429.jpg?v=1580515362" alt="" />
    <label for="chistorra">Txistorra</label>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="Sabores" name="properties[Sabores]">
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        function fillHidden(hiddenname) {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[hidden-data="'+hiddenname+'"]');
        var hiddenfield = document.getElementById(hiddenname);
        hiddenfield.value = ""
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          var x = checkboxes[i];
          if(x.checked){
            if(hiddenfield.value==""){
              hiddenfield.value = x.value;
              }else{
              hiddenfield.value = hiddenfield.value + ", " + x.value; 
              } 
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer as I think you'd check for at least 1 required checkbox before the form is submitted (which would be a separate function). I only cover the issue with the maximum of 4 by adjusting your function `fillhidden()` as follows:

```
  function fillHidden(hiddenname) {
     var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[hidden-data="' + hiddenname + '"]');
     var hiddenfield = document.getElementById(hiddenname);
     hiddenfield.value = "";
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
       var x = checkboxes[i];
       if (x.checked) {
          if (hiddenfield.value == "") {
             hiddenfield.value = x.value;
          } else {
             hiddenfield.value = hiddenfield.value + ", " + x.value;
          }
       }
     }

     let selected = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
     let unselected = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)");
     if (selected == 4) {
       for (var i = 0; i < unselected.length; i++) {
          unselected[i].setAttribute("disabled", 'true');
       }
     } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < unselected.length; i++) {
          unselected[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
     }
 }
```